# Output of parallel computing in R on Windows

Tags: r, windows, for-loop, parallel-processing, iteration

I would like to do some parallel computing in R on Windows.

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

nn = seq(2,20, by=2)
nn2 = rep(-1,10)
vector.accessed.within.iteration = rep(0, 10)

y = foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {

   print(paste0('i = ', i))
   nn2[i] = (nn[i])^2
   vector.accessed.within.iteration[i] = nn[i] + nn2[i]
   nn2[i]
} 

stopCluster(cl)
```

When running the code, `y` is returned as the list of squares from 2 to 20, as intended. However, neither vector `nn2` nor `vector.accessed.within.iteration` are modified within `foreach` loop. Furthermore, the printing `print(paste0('i = ', i))` does not occur.

Is it possible to run iterations of a loop in parallel on windows while also displaying messages and modifying variables from global environment?

Comment: Both questions have been answered several times already here. Please search more carefully.

Comment: @F.Privé Thank you for your comment. I did a search but I did not find an answer to either of questions. Maybe I am not using correct terminology.

Comment: Well it appears that you cannot simply modify variables within foreach loop, you need to return them.

Comment: BTW, see my blog post here https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/ for solutions to your two problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to run iterations of a loop in parallel on windows while ... modifying variables from global environment?

No(*).  All values set inside a `foreach() %dopar% { ... }` construct must be returned at the end of each iteration.  This is by design and philosophy of the **foreach** package.  See 'Example 2: A slightly complicated for-loop' in blog post ['Parallelize a For-Loop by Rewriting it as an Lapply Call'](https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/) from 2019-01-11 (disclaimer: I'm the author) for how to return multiple values.

(*) There exist various workarounds that communicate using other channels, e.g. the file system.  However, such solutions should only be used if all other alternatives have been exhausted and failed.  I highly recommend such alternative solutions because you *will* run into *other types of problems* with those approached.  In your case, you definitely don't need it.

> Is it possible to run iterations of a loop in parallel on windows while also displaying messages ...?

Yes, if you use the [**doFuture**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) foreach adaptor (disclaimer: I'm the author).  When you use that, you will get access to all of the [**future**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework, which includes relaying of output, messages, warnings, and other condition types.  You can read about this in blog post ['future 1.9.0 - Output from The Future'](https://www.jottr.org/2018/07/23/output-from-the-future/) from 2018-07-23 (disclaimer: I'm the author).

```
> library(doFuture)
> registerDoFuture()  ## tell foreach to use the future framework

> ## Create a local cluster of two local workers
> plan(multisession, workers = 2L)

> library(foreach)
> y <- foreach(x = 1:3) %dopar% {
    cat(paste0("x = ", x, "\n"))
    sqrt(x)
  }
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
>
```